# How to make a persistent counter variable in an Android app?

Tags: android

I'm just starting out.

I'm trying to increment a simple counter, every time I run the project on the emulator.

I thought adding an `integer` type `item` in `strings.xml` would help, but that's final, and can't be modified.

Basically I'd just display in my app's first basic screen:

`Started: N` where N would be the Nth time I've launched the project from Eclipse.

How can I make such a counter that's persistent across application launches and exits?

Got it:

```
    SharedPreferences pref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    int tempN=pref.getInt("N", 0);
    tempN++;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putInt("N",tempN);

    editor.commit();

    msgBox.setText("Started:"+tempN);
```

One thing I still don't understand, that when I call `pref.getInt("N",0)`, is the key-value pair `<N,0>` automatically created?

Comment: make use of a shared preference or internal storage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your main activity onCreate():

```
SharedPreferences pref = this.getSharedPreferences();
int count = pref.getInt("your key", 0) //0 is default value.
count++;

SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();
edit.putInt("your key", count);
edit.commit();
// display current count
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use shared preference for that . You can store integer number in shared preference and get value of it when ever you want.

Try this.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Share", Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putInt("Value", 1 );
editor.commit();
```

for get value

```
prefs.getInt("Value",0);
```

Comment: Word. Or, "better" yet, SQLite.  I love me some SQLite. Think like a web designer.  Store persistent data.

Comment: But everytime i start the app, wouldn't `putInt` method be executed everytime and my counter be reset to 1?

Comment: @ronnieaka for that first you need to get value and increment that value and set that to shared preference.

Comment: For a more stable app use `editor.apply()` so it applies the value in the background.